# How to create a trigger in a hospital database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables `infirmier` table

```
CREATE TABLE INFIRMIER
(
    NUM_INF INT 
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EMPLOYE(NUM_EMP) ,
    CODE_SERVICE VARCHAR(50) 
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SERVICE(CODE_SERVICE),
    ROTATION VARCHAR(50), 
    SALAIRE MONEY,

    PRIMARY KEY (NUM_INF),
);
```

and `service`.

```
CREATE TABLE SERVICE
(
    CODE_SERVICE VARCHAR(50)
        PRIMARY KEY (CODE_SERVICE),
    NOM_SERVICE VARCHAR(50),
    BATIMENT INT, 
    DIRECTEUR INT
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES MEDECIN(NUM_MED), 
);
```

I want to create a trigger that would displays a new infirmier assigned to `nom_service` after each insertion of infirmier.

I create also a table `infirmier_tt` to stock in it the new inserting by date and operation.

```
 CREATE TABLE INFIRMIER_tt
 (
     change_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
     NUM_INF INT,
     CODE_SERVICE VARCHAR(50),
     ROTATION VARCHAR(100),
     SALAIRE MONEY,
     NOM_SERVICE VARCHAR(50),
     updated_at DATETIME,
     operation CHAR(3), 
         CHECK(operation = 'INS' OR operation = 'DEL')
);
```

This is the code I'm using

```
CREATE TRIGGER aff_inff 
ON INFIRMIER
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO INFIRMIER_tt(NUM_INF, 
                             --NOM_SERVICE, 
                             CODE_SERVICE, ROTATION, SALAIRE, updated_at, operation)
        SELECT 
            i.NUM_INF , 
            -- NOM_SERVICE from INFIRMIER I join SERVICE S on (I.CODE_SERVICE=S.CODE_SERVICE);
            CODE_SERVICE, 
            ROTATION,
            i.SALAIRE,
            GETDATE(),
            'INS'  
        FROM
            inserted i  
END
```

The problem I'm having is that when I insert a new `infirmier` I can't insert the name of the service `nom_service`, because there isn't in the table `infirmier` and tried to use `join`, but I didn't know how.

This is the results I'm getting when I do an insert:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to join the `INSERTED` pseudo with `Service` table? It's just `... FROM INSERTED I INNERR JOIN Service S ON I.ID = S.ID` and include `S.NOM_SERVICE` column in your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: The problem is i don't know where i'm suppose to put it and if i did when i will insert in infirmier it will say invalid name . nom_service

Comment: okay i will try it!

Comment: no she told us after each insertion of infirmier.

Comment: eh? _"She told us"_??? So, this is a homework.

Comment: Not technically! Cause we didn't study trigger in school. So it's a plus point xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what are you really want to do here, or why it should be this way, but here is what I think you want to do

```
CREATE TABLE  SERVICE(
CODE_SERVICE  varchar(50)primary key (CODE_SERVICE),
NOM_SERVICE varchar(50),
BATIMENT int, 
DIRECTEUR int, 
);


CREATE TABLE INFIRMIER
(
NUM_INF int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
CODE_SERVICE varchar(50),
ROTATION varchar(50), 
SALAIRE money,
CONSTRAINT FK_INF_CODE_SERVICE FOREIGN KEY (CODE_SERVICE) REFERENCES SERVICE(CODE_SERVICE)
);

CREATE TRIGGER TRIG1
ON INFIRMIER
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  -- Change it to an INSERT 
  SELECT * 
  FROM INSERTED I INNER JOIN Service S 
  ON I.CODE_SERVICE = S.CODE_SERVICE;
END

INSERT INTO Service VALUES
('Service1', 'ServiceName1', 1, 1);

INSERT INTO Infirmier(CODE_SERVICE, ROTATION, SALAIRE) VALUES
('Service1', 'Rotation', 100.00);
```

**Returns:**

```
+---------+--------------+----------+----------+--------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
| NUM_INF | CODE_SERVICE | ROTATION | SALAIRE  | CODE_SERVICE | NOM_SERVICE  | BATIMENT | DIRECTEUR |
+---------+--------------+----------+----------+--------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
|       1 | Service1     | Rotation | 100.0000 | Service1     | ServiceName1 |        1 |         1 |
+---------+--------------+----------+----------+--------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
```

As you can see the `NOM_SERVICE` column appears. All what you need now, is to change the `SELECT` statement to an `INSERT`.

I'll leave it for ya as it's a howmework.

**[Here is a live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0adb4b20bc33add6e5e09a1349d26439)** where you can play with it online.

Comment: i want when i insert into infirmier that nom_service appear i mean i could insert into infirmier table too, though it's not an attribut in it.

Comment: @SirinàStrong You said _"no she told us after each insertion of infirmier"_ I did it and the trigger on the `Infirmier` table as you say. And you say _"the column `NOM_SERVICE` should appears"_, and again it appears as you say. So what's the problem there???

Comment: @SirinàStrong Since it solve you problem, please read **[`What should I do when someone answers my question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)**